# Foundation Tab change event

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am doing validation through validation plugin on a page in which tabs getting created through foundation top bar. I want the error messages to be hidden when tab changes.Is there any work around for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in foundation 6:

```
$(selector).on('change.zf.tabs', function() {
         //do something   
});
```